# get the closest local number programmatically using Twiml

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I would like to use the right Twilio phone number I own to make outgoing calls, once I know the destination phone number I need to choose programmatically the local number which can make the call the cheapest possible.

Is there a way to achieve using Twiml and without storing the Twilio Phone numbers in a DB and do checking from my side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can use the REST API to ask Twilio to give you [a list of all of the phone numbers you own](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#list), select the right phone number from that list, then generate the TwiML dynanmically.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It definitely helps! Thanks again Devin.